# Website which offers meme-search functionality and scheduled posting for Facebook

Tags: facebook, social-media, post

I watched a YouTube video 3 months ago about a website which offers scheduled posting for your Facebook page, but also offered a search engine which scraped google for appropriate memes for your Facebook page

for example, if you ran a "Cookie meme" page, you could search "Cookie" in this websites' search engine, then schedule all the images that the website found as Facebook posts, from this site.

In other words, this site offered scheduled posting and also offered a way to find the images to schedule, all in one service.

Does anybody recognise the website I am describing? I used it for a while on my facebook page but have since lost the URL, sorry if this post is vague!